# Display multiple entries from JSON with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, parsing

I need some help with my code, I am noob with JSON and PHP, but I`m learning

```
[
  {
 "eventId": 213,
"balls": [
  {
    "ball": 26,
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "ball": 31,
    "id": 2
  }
]
  },
  {
"eventId": 212,
"balls": [
  {
    "ball": 22,
    "id": 1
      },
  {
    "ball": 33,
    "id": 2
  }
]
}
]
```

I have this JSON and this part of php code:

```
<table>
<?php
$url = 'external-link'; 

$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json_post = json_decode($data,true);
?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($json_post as $event) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $event['eventId']; ?></td>
            <td><?php foreach ($json_post as $ball) : ?> <?php echo $ball['balls'][0]['ball']; ?> <?php endforeach; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a wrong display of this code, but not how I want to be:

```
 213 | 26 31 

 212 | 22 33
```

Any help would be appreciated,thanks

Comment: Loop though $event rather than $ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your inner foreach loop over the current event...

```
<td><?php foreach ($event['balls'] as $ball) : ?> <?php echo $ball['ball']; ?> <?php endforeach; ?></td>
```

In case not all elements have this data, you can use the following...

```
    <td><?php if(isset($event['balls'])):
        foreach ($event['balls'] as $ball) : 
               echo $ball['ball']; 
        endforeach; 
        endif;?></td>
```

---

Full code:

```
$url = "url";
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json_post = json_decode($data,true);
?>
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($json_post as $event) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $event['eventId']; ?></td>
            <td><?php if(isset($event['balls'])):
                foreach ($event['balls'] as $ball) : 
                       echo $ball['ball'].' '; 
                endforeach; 
                endif;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Undefined index: balls and  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), not sure how what to fix

Comment: yes, I have extracted a part from the main JSON, it looks exactly...please have a look at my code:
<table>
<?php

$url = 'url'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$json_post = json_decode($data,true);
?>
<table><tr>
<td><?php foreach ($event['balls'] as $ball) : ?> 
<?php echo $ball['ball']; ?> <?php endforeach; ?></td></tr>
</table>

Comment: I've updated it to the full code I'm using.  I think there were a few tags missing in your version (`</td>` etc)

Comment: Thank you Nigel for your time, you've been very helpful. Finally, it worked.
Many thanks again!